# C: 2 different headers define struct udphdr. How to tell GCC to choose one?

Tags: c, linux, pcap

I am working with pcap code and the struct udphdr seems to be defined in two includes.  How to tell GCC to use a specific one?

Comment: What happens when you include both headers? Does the compiler give an error message? Please post the message. Are the struct udphdr a variable definition, or just a struct type declaration? Do you know if they headers are otherwise different? Do you know which header *must* be included?

Comment: There is no compiler error.  One definition is like this http://www.linuxbase.org/navigator/browse/type_single.php?cmd=display&id=37079 and the other like this http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/udp.h. The compiler seems to only recognize the latter but I believe the first is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Upon looking at /usr/include/netinet/udp.h more carefully the problem is not that the same struct is defined in two different headers.  In this file it is defined as:

```
/* UDP header as specified by RFC 768, August 1980. */
#ifdef __FAVOR_BSD

    struct udphdr {
        u_int16_t uh_sport;  /* source port */
        u_int16_t uh_dport;  /* destination port */
        u_int16_t uh_ulen;   /* udp length */
        u_int16_t uh_sum;    /* udp checksum */
    };

#else

    struct udphdr {
        u_int16_t source;
        u_int16_t dest;
        u_int16_t len;
        u_int16_t check;
    };

#endif
```

So it looks like it is using the POSIX version of the struct which I believe is ok.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to uh_* elements , you must use -D_BSD_SOURCE macro as parameter of gcc, despite you get the following errors:

```
error: ‘struct udphdr’ has no member named ‘uh_sport’
error: ‘struct udphdr’ has no member named ‘uh_dport’
error: ‘struct udphdr’ has no member named ‘uh_ulen’
error: ‘struct udphdr’ has no member named ‘uh_sum’
error: ‘struct udphdr’ has no member named ‘uh_sum’
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a simple way to deal with that. I've done a few tests with `#undef` without success.

I would **re-declare the `struct` you are interested in somewhere else in your own code**, under a different name to avoid clashing, and then use it in the code with this new name.

This approach has problems, of course: what happens if the original header get's updated and that structure changes (some new members, others get removed), you know what I mean?

Answer (score -1):

Just use the right one: `netinet/udp.h` under Linux:

From Linux Standard Base:

http://www.linuxbase.org/navigator/browse/type_single.php?cmd=display&id=37079